# Why are homomorphisms of groups the best choice of morphisms in category of groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Well, "groups" in the question could be replaced by orther algebraic structures.

For example, why don't we let the morphisms be maps between groups not preserving group structure?

The reason I think of is that if we do this, when defining object by universal property, we just get objects up to bijection, rather than up to isomorphism of groups, which is not the way we want them behave.

But are there some other reasons?

Comment: While you could define a category using other morphisms (maps) between "groups", you would probably create confusion if you called that the "category of groups".  The statement about "defining object by universal property" doesn't make clear sense.  If we restrict maps between objects to "isomorphisms" (rather than the more general homomorphisms) of groups, the result would be a category but a rather sterile kind.  Isomorphisms would connect only groups that are essentially identical, so we'd miss out on things that are normally called "universal property" objects.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from defining such a category. It's just useless. Since every set can be given a group structure, and only in a set-many ways, the result is equivalent to $\mathbf{Set}$. You could consider, say, the full subcategory of groups in the category of magmas. This is much less useless, but it still isn't as useful or natural(/expected) as group homomorphisms between groups. There can be only one unambiguous referent for "category of groups", but there are many categories that can have groups as objects. Just use different names for different categories.

Comment: Thank both of you for help!

Comment: @DerekElkins Still have a question, what does useful really mean? As a novice, I think it maybe mean convenience of  formulating statements in group theory?

Comment: @likemath "useful" is a subjective or objective (more often subjective) feeling that something has value. Sometimes it may mean "we can solve some real world problem with that", often it simply means "it helps us solve some interesting math problem" where again "interesting" is subjective. People devlop whole theories from that subjective feeling.

Comment: @DerekElkins: **Group** is actually equivalent to the full subcategory of **Magma** spanned by the groups; in my opinion, the [traditional definition of group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition) and of [group homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_homomorphism) (where the structure is just the binary operation; inverses and identities are existential properties) is actually defining this full subcategory.

Comment: There are other ways of making them categories, e.g., considering only injective homomorphisms, or only surjective ones, or only those with finite kernel and image of finite index. For all of them, isomorphisms are group isomorphisms. These subcategories can in some given context be more useful. We can sometimes consider larger sets of arrows, for instance maps such that $f(gh)(f(g)f(h))^{-1}$ takes finitely many values, and sometimes we can wish to identify some of these maps (in the same way that topological spaces are natural objects for both the topological and the homotopy category).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that you have two groups: $G$ and $H$, for example

$$G=\{0,1,2,3\}$$
$$H=\{5,6,7,8\}$$

I didn't define what group operations are on both $G,H$ but is that necessary? Yes, it is, because we know that there are two groups of order $4$ up to isomorphism. But functions that do not preserve group structure do not care about that. From function's point of view these two groups are the same.

But wait, up to what? Here's the problem. Let's say that $G=\{0,1,2\}$ and since it is of order $3$ then we know that there is a unique (up to isomorphism) group structure on $G$. But we can define a group structure on $G$ in multiple ways (for example by having $0$, $1$ or $2$ as the neutral element) but in reality they are **all the same** because we can freely "translate" the group structure between them. It's a matter of looking at $G$ from a proper angle.

So what is that "translation"? Nothing else then an invertible homomorphism, i.e. an isomorphism. **Necessity is the mother of invention.**

So the reason we use homomorphisms is simply because it is a tool that allows us to analyze relationships between groups. Functions that do not preserve group structure don't really tell us much about that relationship.

Now we can obviously analyze the category of groups with simple functions as morphism. But we don't do that because that doesn't lead to anything useful. Simple as that.

**Final note:** it doesn't mean that the classical homorphism is the best choice. It only means that it is a better choice then plain functions and we didn't find a better candidate yet. But note that sometimes new candidates for morphisms do appear almost like out of nowhere, e.g. the case of the homotopy category.